# How to batch overwrite the entire collection from an array of objects in ReactJS to Firetore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

For example I have an array such as this:

```js
resolvingArray = [
    {
        invoiceId: "user",
        userId: 3
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "test",
        userId: 10
    },
    {
        invoiceId: "yolo",
        userId: 12
    },
]
```

And I want to write the entire array of objects into a Firestore collection. Currently in my Firestore, I have set it up in a way `resolvingCollection/resolving` so here `resolvingInvoices` is the collection and `resolving` is the document. The code I have so far, and this only updates 1 document.

```
export async function updateResolvingInvoices(
  data: DocumentData
): Promise<returnType> {
  if (!checkCounter())
    return { data: null, error: SERVER_COUNTS.ERROR_MAX_COUNT };

  return await setDoc(doc(db, "resolvingInvoices", "resolving"), data)
    .then(() => {
      return { data: true, error: null };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { data: null, error: err };
    });
}
```

How do I rewrite the entire collection instead with the array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

not sure but it seems you're giving the same ID ("resolving") to every document, so you actually store all your data in the same document and you overwrite it every time.

the doc you see uploaded is probably the last one in the list, which didn't get overwritten.

in the example here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data, "LA" should be a unique id.

if you are writing in a subcollection, I think the syntax is `doc(db, "resolvingInvoices/resolving", <id>)`

Edit to answer your comment :

yes, you can have firestore generate the ids for you, it's lower on the page I linked

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id.
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cities"), {
  name: "Tokyo",
  country: "Japan"
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
```

Comment: Ah yes the above is just an example, I want Firestore to automatically generate an ID for every single object in the array. How is it possible though?